# How to map sql Type XML column to string property in NHIbernatre?

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How to map XML column to string property in NHibernate in c#?

The property is defined as :

```
public virtual string Request { get; protected set; }
```

In mapping class I have:

```
Map(o => o.Request).Column("Request").Nullable();
```

I am getting following exception while selecting data from db:

> the data types xml and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. nhibernate

I hope it has something to do with `CustomType<>` but dont know how. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to use XDocument as a property type, and the convention, which will map any property to `"NHibernate.Type.XDocType"`

Complete solution is described here:

#### [Fluent NHibernate and XML columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3721512/1679310)

Where we add convention `Conventions.Add<XmlTypeConvention>();` and define it as:

```
public class XmlTypeConvention : IUserTypeConvention
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Type == typeof(XDocument));
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.CustomType<NHibernate.Type.XDocType>();
    }
}
```

This way we will work with NHibernate dedicated type for xml columns...

Comment: I need the .net property to be 'string' type.

Comment: Question was about mapping xml typy to string property, not XDocument

Comment: @MichalLevý to have mapping between DB and .NET types in your hands ... non standard way ... use custom types. [5.2.3. Custom value types](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-custom): *"It is relatively easy for developers to create their own value types. For example, you might want to persist properties of type Int64 to VARCHAR columns..."*

Comment: @RadimKöhler Well, maybe custom type is not needed in this case. Not using Fluent NH but in standard NH xml mapping specifying `type="StringClob"` does the job...